# Printing a "triangle" of asterisks

Tags: c

The program I am supposed to write is supposed to print the triangle in the following manner:

If the number of rows is 2:

```
       *
      ***
```

If the number of rows is 3:

```
     *
    * *
   *****
```

However, the following code that I did prints the correct amount of stars for the last line, but I am not so sure how I would print the space and the newline. My code for printing the bottom level stars is the following:

```
  void tri_func(num)
{

     int row; int c=1;
     int j;

   for ( row = 1 ; row <= num ; row++ )
   {
      for (j=1; j < row-2; j++) printf(" ");
      for ( c = 1 ; c <= (2*row )- 1-j ; c++ )
      {
        printf("*");
      }

      printf("\n");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you have `n` lines, the first line should contain `n-1` spaces and a `*`. The `i`th line (1< i < n) should contain `n-i` spaces, a `*`, `2i-3` spaces and another `*`, and the last line should contain `2n-1` `*`s. You can easily do it using loops. To print a space, use `printf(" ");`, and remember to print a `\n` in the end of every line.

Comment: I think this would be a bit easier to understand if generalized for any `i` (0≤i<n or 1<i≤n), rather than treating the first and last lines as special.

Comment: Maybe, but since the first line has one `*`, the last line has `2n-1`, and every other line has 2, I think that it makes sense to make them a special case.

Comment: Ah yes, well I was just thinking about the number of leading spaces.

Comment: I don't understand....This is really annoying. I can't seem to get out from printing 3 * on the second row in the number of rows i choose is 3.