# Create a triangle

Tags: c

I need to create a triangle like this

```
 *
 **
 ***
 ****
 *****
```

I have done this. But my triangle does not look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int  k, l;

    for(k=1; k<=5; k++)
    {
        for(l=k; l<=5; l++)
            printf(" ");

        for(l=0; l<=k-1; l++) printf("*");
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

will you tell me where my mistake is?

Comment: Many duplicates, e.g. [Drawing triangle using Asterisks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12711553/drawing-triangle-using-asterisks) and [Printing a “triangle” of asterisks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9244912/printing-a-triangle-of-asterisks) - this seems to be a common homework problem which crops up every year.

Comment: @PaulR about 10 times every year in the time when the new semester begins, to be more precise.

Comment: Still he showed his effort in code and asked for a mistake. Up voting to appreciate that vs those who simply ask others to do their assignments.

Comment: @fayyazkl, I strongly suspect that it is not his code, but code from somewhere else where they solve a slightly different problem.

Comment: @Navnath That is the wrong language tag we should not marking *C* questions as dups of *python* questions.

Comment: @PaulR I realize the concept is similar but those dups are different problems are there no more exact dups?

Comment: @JensGustedt Down voting based upon SUSPICION ONLY that it is code from some where else, unless you get a comment that tells you the dev has no idea about it, doesn't sound right to me. Regarding the other duplicate thing, since this is C Code, cannot tag a python one as duplicate. SO is primarily about code so language does matter IMHO.

Comment: @fayyazkl, I didn't downvote, I rarely do. And come on, if the OP had written this code himself he should have seen where the additional spaces come from.

Comment: @JensGustedt May be. I just remembered my first programming course more than a decade ago where the first assignment I made was printing some extra characters apart from the actual game. I spent several hours thinking what was the cause of it. Then asked a senior to look at it. He took like 2 minutes and first asked me, show me your all print statements and found the issue. The point was as simple, but i just didn't think of checking all printing points. I was soo occupied with thinking in flaw some where in my logic that i missed a trivial thing. May be that was just me.. :)

Answer (score 3):

You do not need 3 loops - that is unnecessary:

```
int  k, l;
for(k=1; k<=5; k++)  // outer loop
{
    for(l=0; l<k; l++) // inner loop
        printf("*");
    printf("\n");

}
```

The idea is simple keep printing stars in inner loop as long as `l` is less than `k`. So as the row-number increases (tracked by `k`) so does the number of stars. Your fixed code:

```
for(k=1; k<=5; k++)
    {
        for(l=0; l<=k-1; l++) printf("*");
        printf("\n");
    }
```

Comment: You could abstract out the inner loop: `void printn(int n, char* s) { while (0 < n--) { printf(s); } }` and call it like `printn(k, "*")`

Comment: +1 for explaining the code ... I would take out the word simple since that is a subjective, if these problems were simple to everyone then they would not be asked

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the loop printing space. Rest of the code seems fine