# c code to print a triangle made of '*'?

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

I wanted to write a C program which could print a triangle made of asterisks. Based on number of rows given by user. It should look like the one given in code sample. But I am not getting desired result. Can someone find the error in code? Please note I am a beginner and I don't care about runtime and all, so please provide the simplest code possible. Thanks.

**Output**

---

```
*
**
***
```

**Code Listing**

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int r;
    int rp=1;
    int cp=1;
    printf("enter number of rows: ");
    scanf("%d", &r);
    while(rp<=r)
    {
        while (cp<=rp)
        {
            printf("* %s\n");
            cp=cp+1;
        }
        rp=rp+1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `printf("* %s\n");` -- What is `%s` doing there?

Comment: @CoolGuy Nothing, Sandeep107 pointed it out in his answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a triangle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19180377/create-a-triangle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cp` is not being reset in your outer loop.

The code you provided would be much easier to read by making use of `for` loops as well, since your initial conditions, exit conditions, and per-loop operations; are all listed on one line.

**Code Listing**

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int rows;
    printf("Enter number of rows: ");
    scanf("%d", &rows);
    int i, j;
    for ( i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
    {
        for ( j = 0; j <= i; j++ )
        {
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Sample Output**

---

```
Enter number of rows: 10
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******
********
*********
**********
```

However, if you insist on using your original style, you just need to add `cp = 1` after the first while loop.

**Alternate Code Listing**

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int r;
    int rp=1;
    int cp=1;
    printf("enter number of rows: ");
    scanf("%d", &r);
    while(rp<=r)
    {
        while (cp<=rp)
        {
            printf("*");
            cp=cp+1;
        }
        cp = 1;
        printf("\n");
        rp=rp+1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

If you know you'll be iterating over a fixed range, `for` loops are your friend. If you'll be looping forever until the user enters specific input, or you're polling some function/process/peripheral until a status changes, then you're likely going to want a `while` loop. Take advantage of this time to read up on the differences between `for`, `while`, and `do-while` loops, and the difference between entry-condition and exit-condition loops.

Finally, as one of the other people who answered noted: **Get in the habit of having indexes start a zero, not one**. It will save you a lot of pain in the future getting used to using `[0, n-1]` indexing rather than `[1, n]` indexing.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks, I will keep these things in mind ;)

Answer (score 2):

You should initialize cp to 1 before second  while loop.

Also, no need of %s while printing

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to set `cp` to 1 in your first while. By the way, you should take the habit to start you counters at 0 (It means you should use `<` instead of `<=`)

Comment: but I used cp<=rp and not cp<rp, so since initially both cp and rp are 1, so things should work out according to me. What are your views on this?

Comment: It works, I'm just saying you should take good habits ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int r;
    int rp=1;
    int cp=1;
    printf("enter number of rows: ");
    scanf("%d", &r);
    while(rp<=r)
    {
        while (cp<=rp)
        {
            printf("* %s\n");
            cp=cp+1;
        }
        cp = 1;
        printf("\n");
        rp=rp+1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```